# java sort array where it's position matters

Tags: java, sorting

lets say i have this array

```
int [] array= new int[26];
```

it has 26 places because the position 0 is 'a' , position 1'b' ... position 25 is 'z'
so in each position i have an int number so

```
if in position array[0]=5 it means i have 5 'a'
if in position array[1]=6 it means i have 6'b'
if in position array[0]=0 it means that i do not have the 'a' letter
```

what i want is to find in each loop the 2 smallest frequencies and the letters of the two smallest frequencies

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        if(array[i]==0)
        continue;       
        else{
            cmin1=(char)('a'+i);
            posi=i;                 
            min1=array[posi] ;
            break;
        }
            for(int j=posi+1;j<array.length;j++){
            if(array[j]==0)
                continue;   
            else if(array[j]<=min1){
                posj=posi;
                posi=j;
                cmin2=cmin1;
                cmin1=(char)(j+'a');    
                min2=min1;
                min1=array[j];
            }
```

i have tried this which is wrong

Comment: and what have you tried till now, yourself?

Comment: is it homework? what are the conditions?

Comment: i have tried to find the smallest letter but i cannot find the second smallest especially if the frequencies increase in each time

Comment: its a very small part of my whole program

Comment: Since this is homework, I'll just outline a solution.  Loop through the array.  If the element is smaller than the smallest you've found, clear a List and add the position in a List.  If the element is the same as the smallest you've found, add the position in a List.  When the loop is finished, you'll have a List of the smallest occurrences.  Take the first two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort would work but it's not the best performing method.

How about a single loop which would be O(n)?

```
int min1 = Integer.MAX_INT;
int idx1 = -1;
int min2 = Integer.MAX_INT;
int idx2 = -1;

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    // skip empty items
    if(array[i]==0)
         continue;

    if (array[i] < min1) {
         min2 = min1;
         idx2 = idx1;
         min1 = array[i];
         idx1 = i;
    }
    else if (array[i] < min2) {
         min2 = array[i];
         idx2 = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java is Object Oriented so...

Let's take a class, which name would be LetterFrequency
LetterFrequency has 2 attributes:
    1) Char character
    2) Integer occurrences

You need to sort the LetterFrequency objects by their "occurrences" atrribute. To do that, make LetterFrequancy implements Comparable and define method compareTo() accordingly.

Then put all your LetterFrequency objects in a List and use the method

```
Lists.sort(yourList)
```

Answer (score 0):

sort the array first...now apply the searching algorithm...and here you go
once you find the smallest element you can get the second smallest as the array is already sorted...i guess there would be no difficulty doing this...for sorting you can use quicksort  with complexity(nlogn)...hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the smallest element in an array, you can use the following code :

```
List<int> list = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(array));

// Print the smallest element of your array
System.out.println(Collections.min(list));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class representing each frequency count.  Then I would create a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which orders the records by the frequency.  Then I would use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29) or [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort the collection using the `Comparator`.

Alternatively, if you simply want to find the entries in the array but can't change your data type, then you need to define an algorithm for *searching* (not *sorting*) the array.  To do this, and do it in one pass, I would define local variables for the positions and corresponding frequencies of the two least frequently occurring.  Initialize the least to the first item in the array, then proceed by comparing the current one and if it is less then rotate the values of the variables which are keeping track.  At the end you'll have the two least frequent.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this array declaration will never work:

```
 int [] array= new array[26];
```

You need:

```
 int [] array= new int[26];
```